# Trouble executing Perl script in C# Web Application

Tags: c#, perl, iis, iis-7

Simply, I am having issues with executing a Perl script with input parameters within a C# Web Application.  I have no problem executing the code from a Console application, but within my web app, I receive no response.

The code I am using is:

```
ProcessStartInfo cmdStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
cmdStartInfo.FileName = "C:\gnu\perl.exe";
cmdStartInfo.Arguments = "run.pl --day=1 --format=2";
cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmdStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmdStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmdStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = TEMP_DIRECTORY;

Process cmdProcess = new Process();
cmdProcess.StartInfo = cmdStartInfo;
cmdProcess.OutputDataReceived += cmd_DataReceived;
cmdProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

// Start
cmdProcess.Start();
cmdProcess.WaitForExit();
```

and

```
static void cmd_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // Breakpoint to DEBUG here
    string result = e.Data;
}
```

I am using IIS 7.  I wonder if it is an issue in there?  I am using Identity Impersonate and Windows Authentication.

Comment: As an update, I can successfully get the information when I am using the Visual Studio Development Server, but not on an IIS Server.

Comment: Does it work if CreateNoWindow is false? ActivePerl comes with a `wperl.exe` which works without a console, but I think its `perl.exe` expects a console.

Comment: What error do you exactly have? Did you check the error stream for info?

Comment: I checked Standard Error and there was no error in StandardError.  It was an empty string.

Comment: The error that is occurring is that perl is not executing when I'm running an application hosted in IIS.  I have gotten Perl to show a response when calling the perl.exe, but not with other command line parameters.  ex `(perl.exe filename.pl --otherparams=1)`

Comment: Try setting `cmdStartInfo.Arguments = "/K C:\gnu..."` or `cmdStartInfo.Arguments = "/C C:\gnu..."`

Comment: What's the exit code?

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.  I have been able to temporarily resolve the issue by granting full control permissions to the directory, in which the script is located.  Please let me know if you there are better ways of accomplishing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a Permissions issue.  I had to grant permissions on the directory containing the script to be executed using the Perl command.

For example, the permissions would be given to the directory, dir1 in this example:

```
perl.exe dir1/script.pl
```

Originally I only granted permissions on the folder that contained the perl.exe file, which did not resolve the issue.

Comment: I have similar problem, how to grant permission?