# Trouble executing Perl script in C# Web Application after deployed on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, perl

I am having issues with executing a Perl script with input parameters within a `C# Web Application` after I deploy it on `IIS`. I have no problem executing the code from Visual Studio. I am using `IIS 7 and .Net framework 4.0`.

I referred to link [Trouble executing Perl script in C# Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15695868/trouble-executing-perl-script-in-c-sharp-web-application)
but could not get what permissions and for which user I need to set the permissions.

The code I am using is:

```
try
{
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    procStartInfo.FileName = @"perl.exe";
    procStartInfo.Arguments = (string)command;
    procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    procStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;

    proc.Start();
    result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
catch (Exception objException)
{
    Response.Write(objException.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Is the perl script located in the same folder of the web app?